# What is the function of CETP?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism, lipids, fat-metabolism, cholesterol

I read up that CETP transfers cholesterol from HDL, which collected it from tissues, to VLDL. This VLDL is then sent back to the tissues, ultimately forming LDL internalised by cells.

What is the whole point in taking cholesterol from the tissues only to give it back? I read up that reverse cholesterol transport is for sending the excess cholesterol to the liver for excretion as bile. But LDL receptors are [everywhere](http://biogps.org/#goto=genereport&id=3949) and not just the liver.

There also happens to be a SRB1 pathway specific to the liver but apparently not significant in humans :(

So pls help me make sense.